onLogin is not a function (it is undefined)
Estoy codificando en react native con expo y typescript. Tengo los siguiente códigos:
context/AuthContext.tsx


import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";

interface AuthProps {
  //authState nos dará información del estado del usuario como token, si está autenticado y el id del usuario
  authState: {
    token: string | null;
    authenticated: boolean | null;
    user_id: string | null;
  };
  onRegister: (email: string, password: string) => Promise < any > ;
  onLogin: (email: string, password: string) => Promise < any > ;
  onLogout: () => Promise < any > ;
  initialized: boolean;
}

const TOKEN_KEY = "my-stream-token";
export const API_URL = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL;
const AuthContext = createContext < Partial < AuthProps >> ({}); //Creamos el contexto de autenticación

//Creamos el provider de autenticación que se encargará de manejar el estado de autenticación
export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({
  children
}: any) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState < {
    token: string | null;
    authenticated: boolean | null;
    user_id: string | null;
  } > ({
    token: null,
    authenticated: null,
    user_id: null,
  });
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

  //Obtener el token del usuario
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadToken = async() => {
      //Cargar token al iniciar
      const data = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);

      if (data) {
        const object = JSON.parse(data);
        //Establecemos nuestro estado de contexto
        setAuthState({
          token: object.token,
          authenticated: true,
          user_id: object.user.id,
        });
      }
      setInitialized(true);
    };
    loadToken();
  }, []);

  //Iniciar sesión
  const login = async(email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      //Hacer la petición al servidor
      const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password
        }),
      });

      const json = await result.json();

      //Estado de autenticación
      setAuthState({
        token: json.token,
        authenticated: true,
        user_id: json.user.id,
      });

      //Guardar el token en el almacenamiento seguro
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, JSON.stringify(json));

      return json;
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        error: true,
        msg: (e as any).response.data.msg
      };
    }
  };

  //Registrar usuario
  const register = async(email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}/register`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password
        }),
      });

      const json = await result.json();
      console.log("registrado: ", json);

      //Estado de autenticación
      setAuthState({
        token: json.token,
        authenticated: true,
        user_id: json.user.id,
      });

      //Guardar el token en el almacenamiento seguro
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, JSON.stringify(json));
      return json;
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        error: true,
        msg: (e as any).response.data.msg
      };
    }
  };

  //Cerrar sesión
  const logout = async() => {
    //Limpiar el almacenamiento seguro
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);

    //Limpiar el estado de autenticación
    setAuthState({
      token: null,
      authenticated: false,
      user_id: null,
    });
  };

  const value = {
    onRegister: register,
    onLogin: login,
    onLogout: logout,
    authState,
    initialized,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value = {
    value
  } > {
    children
  } < /AuthContext.Provider>;
};



Y también: app/index.tsx


import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import React, {
  useState
} from "react";
import Spinner from "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";
import {
  useAuth
} from "../context/AuthContext";

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;


const Page = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const {
    onLogin,
    onRegister
  } = useAuth();


  //Función para iniciar sesión 
  const onSignInPress = async() => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await onLogin!(email, password);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert("Error", 'No se pudo iniciar sesión');
      Alert.alert("Error", e.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  //Función para registrarse
  const onSignUpPress = async() => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await onRegister!(email, password);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert("Error", 'No se pudo registrar');
      Alert.alert("Error", e.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    // KeyboardAvoidingView Sirve para que el teclado no tape el input
    <
    KeyboardAvoidingView style = {
      styles.container
    }
    behavior = {
      Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"
    } >
    <
    Spinner visible = {
      loading
    }
    /> <
    Text style = {
      styles.header
    } > ReuMeet < /Text> <
    Text style = {
      styles.subheader
    } > La forma más rápida de reunirse < /Text>

    <
    Text > Correo electrónico < /Text> <
    TextInput autoCapitalize = "none"
    placeholder = "Correo electrónico"
    value = {
      email
    }
    onChangeText = {
      setEmail
    }
    style = {
      styles.inputField
    }
    /> <
    Text style = {
      {
        marginTop: 20
      }
    } > Contraseña < /Text> <
    TextInput placeholder = "Contraseña"
    value = {
      password
    }
    onChangeText = {
      setPassword
    }
    secureTextEntry style = {
      styles.inputField
    }
    />

    <
    TouchableOpacity onPress = {
      onSignInPress
    }
    style = {
      styles.button
    } >
    <
    Text style = {
      {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    } > Iniciar sesión < /Text> < /
    TouchableOpacity >

    <
    Button title = "¿No tienes una cuenta? Regístrate"
    onPress = {
      onSignUpPress
    }
    color = {
      Colors.primary
    }

    /> < /
    KeyboardAvoidingView >
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: WIDTH > HEIGHT ? '30%' : 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  subheader: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  inputField: {
    marginVertical: 4,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 4,
    padding: 10,
  },
  button: {
    marginVertical: 15,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    padding: 12,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});

export default Page;



Lo que sucede es que al ejecutar la aplicación y llenar los campos de correo y contraseña y dar clic en iniciar sesión me aparece el mensaje de onLogin is not a function (it is undefined) y lo mismo con onRegister. Al parecer hay alguna mala importación del auth y no esta siendo correctamente llamado. He intentado varias formas de cambiarlo y sigue de la misma manera
